How can I update data in vue.js?
I am new to vue.js and I try to update data. I write this code for pencil icon
<i class="mdi mdi-pencil"
 v-b-modal.updateHolidayType
 ></i>

I write this for modal
<b-modal
                  id="updateHolidayType"
                  title="Update holiday"
                  centered
                  hide-footer>
                  <ModalForm
                   cardTitle="Update holiday"
                   description="Update holiday"
                   :holiday="holiday"
                   @holidayUpdated="holidayUpdated"/>
                </b-modal>

and this for form
EditForm() {
  const holidayTypesId = this.holidayTypes
    .filter((e) => e.title === this.holidayTypeValue)
    .map((item) => item.id);

  session
    .put(`api/person/holiday/${this.holidayId}/update/`, {
      holidays_start_date: this.startDate,
      holidays_end_date: this.endDate,
      comments: this.comments,
      person: this.$route.params.id,
      holiday_type: holidayTypesId,
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.alertShow = !this.alertShow;
      this.alertVariant = 'success';
      this.alertMsg = 'Updated';
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$emit('holidayUpdated');
      }, 1500);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      this.alertShow = !this.alertShow;
      this.alertVariant = 'danger';
      this.alertMsg = e.response.data;
    });
}

But when I click on pencil I go in empty page. When I click on pencil I want the page to show a modal which have the data and I can edit them. How can I do this?

Please provide some more code for the event trigger on the icon as well as the ModalForm component. Also where is EditForm used?

the icon code doesn't make much sense.  what is v-b-modal.updateHolidayType?  I have no clue what it's purpose is.  generally, I would expect some click event on the icon, that calls a function or otherwise sets a modal's visibility to true.  The visibility is, again generally, controlled by a v-model on the modal component.

Also, it also looks like you're using third party library components, it would be helpful to include that information in your question to receive more specific help.  and as the [vue.js] tag states: "Vue.js questions are highly version specific and should always be tagged with [vuejs2] or [vuejs3] in addition to this tag". Please let us know what framework/library versions you're working with
